# Angular: Data on Component's View Only Update When Performing Click Action

Tags: angularjs, service, components

I forked an example from Angular 1's tutorial:

```
https://plnkr.co/edit/I48XFq
```

- 2 controllers (MainCtrl and AltCtrl) reference to the same Hero data from one dataService
- MainCtrl and AltCtrl use a heroDetail component to render view of data

My setup:

- dataService udpates data.time every 3 seconds using setInterval (I'm trying to not use Angular's $interval to get data rendered on view)

```js
    .factory('dataService', function() {
      var data = {};
    
      data.location = "Safe House";
      data.count = 0;
    
      data.time = new Date();
      setInterval(function() {
        data.time = new Date();
        data.count++;
      }, 1000);
    
      data.updateLocation = function(origin) {
        if (origin === 'click') return;
        data.location = "Safe House #" + data.count;
      }
    
      return data;
    });
```

- In the heroDetail view, I put a button that invoke dataService.updateLocation('click'). Invoking from this button will do nothing, just return.
- Also in the heroDetail controller, there's a setInterval to call dataService.updateLocation('setInterval') that actually update data.location

  ```
    function HeroDetailController(dataService) {
  var $ctrl = this;
  $ctrl.update = function() {
    dataService.updateLocation('click');
  }

  setInterval(function() {
    dataService.updateLocation('setTimeout');
  }, 3000);      }
  ```

Result:

- The service's data though gets udpate via background setInterval, but is not rendered on component view
- But when I click on the front-end button, data is rendered with latest udpate, dispite the button just do nothing on data.

Could you help to explain why and how data got updated from service to the view in this case?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using built-in `$interval` service instead of `window.setInterval` may solve your problem. [AngularJs $interval documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)

To understand the problem, first read about JavaScript event loop. [Event loop explained here](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)
AngularJS $digest loop is based on event loop and after each digest cycle, it updates DOM according to the model that is two-way bound to the view. [$digest cycle explained here](http://techiejs.com/Blog/Post/Understanding-The-AngularJS-Digest-Loop)

Comment: I know the $interval will work, but I just wonder why clicking the button cause UI to update, even when the funtion just return and do nothing. 

Thank you for the $digest cycle explained link, that's a valuable post for me.

Comment: I did, and additionally found [this article](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html) that give a specific info:

The `$digest()` function is called whenever AngularJS thinks it is necessary. For instance, **after a button click handler** has been executed.

That means when the button handler is executed, even the handler do nothing but a new digest cycle is still called and make things work.

Comment: I got your point now. Your setInterval anonymous functions are out of angular world; but ng-click event is in it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should add to your "setInterval" function the following line of code:
data.location = "Safe House #" + data.count;

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please edit your answer to provide more details and an explanation why that would be a solution.

Comment: I think that's not the case. I'm just wondering why the button click generate UI update, while the setInterval doesn't.